# Why superposition theorem has not been executed here?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, superposition

Here is the given circuit[image]

In this problem while finding V1 we didn’t took the voltage contribution at that point by Vo(Superposition theorem)Only current source Is has been used to find the voltage at V1.

**Why we didn’t consider the effect of Vo on V1?What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply superposition, you need to consider all the independent sources which are connected in the circuit, take their contributions and add them. Your circuit has only one independent source, the current source, connected to it. So only \$i_s\$ will be considered. \$V_O\$ is not a source voltage but is a result of applying the input source current.